# assets pipline - create multiple application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jruby

We are developing a solution for an intranet application which runs on chromium embedded framework and 
mobile devices (ios)

We have a problem with high loading times. One part of that problem is that our `application.js` is over 1MB 
(minified) so we are considering to reduce the size of this file by splitting it up into several versions of the file,
so that each site can call an optimized form of the `application.js` only containing the parts of the js it requires.
e.g. we are using `ckeditor` on some of the pages - so the assets for `ckeditor` should be delivered only if they are required.

My question is how to configure the assets pipeline to produce multiple versions of `application.js`

Our Setup:
jruby, rails, puma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create other js manifests in the same format, and make these precompiled in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile << 'some_other_application.js'
```

Include in views the same way.

Comment: thank you works perfekt - i moved  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile to an initializer

Answer (score 1):

To add to `@vasfed`'s answer, you'll need to look at creating other asset files (they *can't* be called `application.js`):

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :application, (:cms if controller_name == "posts") %>
```

The above will basically add `application.js` and `cms.js` to your layout; `cms` *only* being loaded if the controller is `PostsController`.

--

You'd need to add the file to the `assets.rb` initializer, and prevent `application`'s manifest directive from loading it:

```
#app/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( cms.js )

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree .
//= stub cms
```

You can then add as many [sprockets manifest directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) to the `cms.js` file as you need:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - it works perfekt, but Vasfed postet the first correct answer

Comment: Certainly, I'm glad it worked and hope it gave context